# Goodwillie calculus and morphisms of functors

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory

Let $F,G: \mathcal{T}\to \mathcal{S}$ be two functors from topological spaces to spectra (or topological spaces) and let $s: F\to G$ be a morphism between them.
Suppose $F$ and $G$  are analytic and we are given their Goodwillie towers.
What can we say about $s$ in terms of the towers? Can we describe all morphisms between functors in terms of their towers?